# Enter key is acting very strange, even in virtual keyboard

Tags: browser, window

enter key is registering all the control keys(shift ctrl alt home end) along with D and C, also they seems to be pressed for many times(10 ~ 20) for ~ 1 second. this happens in on screen virtual keyboard as well. This happens in all my browsers.

Answer (score 0):

---

- Disconnect your keyboard and try again with the virtual keyboard.

I would say you have some key or other stuck on your physical keyboard. 
If you still experience this issue with the physical keyboard disconnected you might want to follow [these](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) steps as you might have your system corrupted.
Should your problem be the physical keyboard, it's time for a rousing round of lift up your keyboard and try to spot the optical illusion between the 'J' & 'K' keys on your keyboard while you shake it vigorously above your head...*cough*.. or clean it up thoroughly.